# Set Font in ListView. marathi(kiran.ttk)

Tags: android

[image]
help me to set font in marathi (kiran.ttf) listview. font copied in res-font folder.

Comment: Biggest tip I can give you is to post your code as text. That will increase your chance to get help a lot!

Comment: Thanks but it gives error when i past code. also add 4 spaces. i am new to android .

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO

You can use this class which crawles all views inside a viewgroup and changes their font

```
public class FontChangeCrawler
{
private Typeface typeface;

public FontChangeCrawler(Typeface typeface)
{
    this.typeface = typeface;
}

public FontChangeCrawler(AssetManager assets, String assetsFontFileName)
{
    typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(assets, assetsFontFileName);
}

public void replaceFonts(ViewGroup viewTree)
{
    View child;
    for(int i = 0; i < viewTree.getChildCount(); ++i)
    {
        child = viewTree.getChildAt(i);
        if(child instanceof ViewGroup)
        {
            // recursive call
            replaceFonts((ViewGroup)child);
        }
        else if(child instanceof TextView)
        {
            // base case
            ((TextView) child).setTypeface(typeface);
        }
    }
}
}
```

then in the list view adapters in `getView` method:

```
FontChangeCrawler fontChanger = new FontChangeCrawler(context.getAssets(), "fonts/IRANSansMobile(FaNum).ttf");
    fontChanger.replaceFonts((ViewGroup)v);
```

and in the activities:

```
FontChangeCrawler fontChanger = new FontChangeCrawler(getAssets(), "fonts/IRANSansMobile(FaNum).ttf");
    fontChanger.replaceFonts((ViewGroup)this.findViewById(android.R.id.content));
```